# Web : background blink

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have to change a background image based on a mousehover event.

```
$("#videoLanceur").mouseenter(function() {
    $("body#homebg").css("background-image", "url(img/home-labtop-clean-playerhovered.jpg)");
})
$("#videoLanceur").mouseleave(function() {
    $("body#homebg").css("background-image", "url(img/home-labtop-clean-player.jpg)");
})
```

It works fine, but ... on the first mouse hover, the background blinks. I guessed it was because it had to load the image.

So I decided to preload the image.

```
HTML :
<div id="hiddenPreloadedBgImage">
  <img src="img/home-labtop-clean-playerhovered.jpg" />
</div>

CSS :
#hiddenPreloadedBgImage {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: -500%;
    top: -500%;
}
```

I was happy, it works fine on chrome, but not on firefox neither on internet explorer (ie 11 is enough for me)

So here I am, if you guys have any idea ?

Comment: You could use a CSS sprite.

Comment: Use fade in fade out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define two different Divs with both backgrounds:

```
<div id="id1">
 <img src="http://www.osmobot.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/1379369265_Google_2.png" />
</div>

<div id="id2">
  <img src="http://www.truckcentrewa.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Google+-150x150.png" />
</div>
```

Set css of one to hidden and one to visible:

```
#id1 {
 display:none;
 position: absolute;
}
#id2 {
 display:block;
 position: absolute;

}

#id1 img{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
}

#id2 img{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
}
```

And display one remove other:

```
jQuery("#id1").mouseenter(function() {
  jQuery("#id1").css("display","none");
  jQuery("#id2").css("display","block");
});

jQuery("#id2").mouseleave(function() {
  jQuery("#id2").css("display","none");
  jQuery("#id1").css("display","block");
});
```

Edit:    http://jsfiddle.net/9afmxxad/

**Tested Code**

Comment: The thing is  : the background image is on the body, witch contains many other html code that I cannot duplicate.

Comment: make a div that is right below the body and remove the background from body and place it in the div and let div cover whichever part of the page you need. It is more practical since you will have more control over the div and less css in your body.. therefore more control on what you want to do with the div

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/rrkzLstr/1/)**

Edit : added transition after the comments below.

why not use `css` only with `transition`?

css

```
#test {
   background-image: url('http://www.osmobot.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/1379369265_Google_2.png');
   height: 100px;
   width: 120px;
    transition: all 0.1s;
}

#test:hover {
   background-image: url('http://www.truckcentrewa.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Google+-150x150.png');
}
```

Comment: @PeeHaa : it does, image will not blink if you try it with css instead of changing the url with jquery on mouse hover.

Comment: It does blink either way. You already have the image in cache probably.

Comment: @PeeHaa : hmm it may be the case. What if I add transition to it?

Comment: I like your solution, it's simple and effective, but the mouse hover is not on the same element as the background image. As you can see on my code sample, the image is under the body #homebg, but the mouse over is on another div, named #videolanceur. Sorry, I should have emphasised this specificity.